# Propagating images/photos to other servers

Tags: sql-server, webserver

On one server, I have to create photos/images for download.

There is one more server outside of the same LAN that I have to sync my images (both add/delete) to, to help share the load.

Is there a good software to achieve this easily, or do I have to write code to sync the software to another server?

I'm not storing images in the database so I can't sync using built-in database replication. Or is there a specialised SQL database that is specially built for such image sync/replication purposes?

Comment: You might look at [DFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dfs/distributed-file-system-dfs-functions)

Comment: I may use windows on main server, but linux on secondary server... DFS may need me to use all-Windows system? any other solutions?